# Why can you cancel zero terms in the numerator and denominator of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is link to some limit questions:

[image: Example]
Can anyone explain how has answers were derived? In (a), how can we cancel out $(x-2)$? And how can answer be 0? When $x\to 2$, $x-2\to 0$ and the answer should be infinity. Similarly in (b) the answer should be infinity. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Notice that for all $y\neq 0$ one has $\frac{y}{y}=1$.  Similarly, for all $x\neq 2$ one has $\frac{x-2}{x-2}=1$ and for all $x\neq 2$ one has $\frac{2(x-2)}{x-2}=2$ etc...  Division by zero is never guaranteed to be "infinity" unless the numerator is also nonzero.  In the case that the numerator is also zero more care needs to be used.  These examples showcase instances where $\lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ act differently despite $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)=0$

Comment: A friendly reminder that we are not allowed to factor out something that is explicitly equal to zero from both numerator and denominator, but as we are looking at the *limit* as $x\to 2$, $x$ is never explicitly *equal* to $2$ and so $x-2$ is never explicitly *equal* to zero so the factoring is allowed.

Comment: 1) $\frac 00 \ne \infty$.  $\frac 00$ is simply a meaningless undefined statement.  So $f(0)$ doesn't exist.  But $lim_{n\to a}f(x) \ne f(a)$ nesc.  If $x$ is *near* $2$ then $x-2\ne 0$.  So we can cancel out $x-2$ for values *near* 2.  So for $x$ *near* 2 we have $f(x)$ is *near*  $\frac {2-2}{2+2} = 0$.

Comment: You can to learn [write nice formulas with our tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). On the other hand if you want,  you've also this online editor [TexPaste](http://www.texpaste.com/). And with the right click of your mouse over a formula edited in this site Mathematics Stack Exchange, choosing *>Show Math As*, and after *>Tex Commands* you can perform copy&paste and after  modify such code. Isn't required a response of this comment, and good week.

Answer (score 3):

There's a factor of $(x-2)$ in the denominator, and two factors of $(x-2)$ in the numerator. The cancelling removes one factor of each. What remains is

$$\frac{x-2}{x+2}$$

As $x$ approaches $2$, the numerator approaches $0$ and the denominator approaches $4$. This is a well defined quotient: $0/4=0$, which gives you the answer.

---

The key thing to note here is that limits consider what happens **near** $x=2$, but **not** *at* $x=2$. Near $x=2$, $(x-2)$ is not $0$ and hence the cancellation is valid.

This is also a good example that limits involving division by zero need not diverge to infinity. In fact, they can diverge to $-\infty$ or $+\infty$, converge to anything in between, or even have some other, more wild behavior.

Comment: Indeed limits involving numerator and denominator both tending to zero are used to define the derivative of a function.

Answer (score 2):

Big Picture.

1) If $f(x) = \frac {(x-2)^2}{(x-2)(x+2)}$ then $f(0) = \frac 00$ which is undefined (not $\infty$ by the way; simply undefined and meaningless).

However and values very very close to $x =2$ but not actually precisely $x=2$ all the $f(x)$ will have values that are very close to a value $k$.  That is what we mean when you say $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}f(x) = k$.  We are saying "if $x$ is close to but not necessarily equal to$2$, then $f(x)$ is close to but not necessarily equal to $k$

Of course, we have to be technically precise and formal about it (which the above most certainly is not).

so.... we are looking at values of $x$ where $x$ is *NOT* equal to $2$.

2).  If $M = \frac {AB}{AC}$ and $A \ne 0$ then we can divide $M = \frac {\not AB}{\not A C} = \frac AC$.

And if $x$ is not equal to $2$ then $x -2 \ne 0$.  So we can "cancel" $x-2$ out.

So for $x \ne 2$ then $f(x) =\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x-2)(x+2)} \frac {\not{(x-2)}(x-2)}{\not{(x-2)}(x+2)} = \frac {x-2}{x+2}$.

This new expression at $x = 2$ will be $\frac {2-2}{2+2} = \frac 04 = 0$.

This is *not* $f(2)$ (which is still undefined) but an all $x$ very close but not equal to $2$ then $f(x) = \frac {(x-2)(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+2)}$ is very close to but not equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

They simply use the following rule to simplify fractions when there's a common factor in the numerator and the denominator:
$$\frac{A\color{blue}\not\! C}{B\color{blue}\not\! C}=\frac AB,$$
and they determine the limit of the simplified fraction.

Comment: This restates the "what" that the OP observed, but doesn't answer the "why" the OP asked for...

Comment: It answers ‘how can we cancel out $x-2$?’ which I thought the main point in the post

Comment: It seemed to me the poster was asking for an explanation of this rule, rather than a statement to the effect that we could use this rule. But you could be right. Guess we'll see what happens...

Answer (score -1):

If there be a given limit like the one given underneath:

$$\lim_{x \to 2}~ \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$

As it can be seen that as the denominator tends to $~0~$ the limit approaches to infinity,and therefore we cancel out both $~(x-2)~$ from numerator as well as from denominator.

The final result comes like this:

$$\lim_{x \to 2} (x+2)$$

Which can be easily simplified by putting the limit value,i.e.,$~2~$

But my question arises out from the point that "is it correct to cancel out  $~(x-2)~$ from both numerator and denominator ?", as 
$$x-2\implies 2-2\implies 0$$
and we can't cancel out $~\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)~$ as it is an intermediate form. And if this be the case then we can also prove that $~\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)~$ is $~\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)~$,$~2~$,$~\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)~$ etc.
$$\frac{10(10-10)}{30(10-10)}\implies \frac{10}{30}\implies \frac{1}{3}$$
Here $~(10-10)~$ gets cancelled out both from both numerator as well as from the denominator just like the previous problem where $~\frac{x-2}{x-2}~$ got cancelled out from the numerator as well as from the denominator.

Note:I am just a class $11$ student,and that also a beginner,so I might be wrong at somewhere,so please help me to figure it out and let me rectify my mistake...

My question

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please use MathJax